# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Error when trying to connect to SAP Datasphere by using powershell function app in azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, odbc

I'm attempting to establish a connection to my SAP Datasphere database using a PowerShell script within an Azure Function App. However, I've encountered a challenge as it seems not feasible to install the necessary drivers directly into the Azure Function App environment, and I'm struggling to identify an appropriate driver for this purpose.

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$connectionString = @"
Driver={HDBODBC};ServerNode=e510.hanacloud.ondemand.com:443;UID=PROFICO;PWD=8,*SZ_U_s:WvW;
"@


$con = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection $connectionString
$con.Open()
$sql = "SELECT top 10 MATNR as MaterialNumber, TO_DATE(ERSDA)  as CreatedOn, WERKS as Plant, MAKTX as Description, LVORM as DeletionFlag, MTART as MaterialType, BESKZ as ProcurmentType FROM PROFITABILITY_SP.VIEW_MATERIAL_MASTER"
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand $sql, $con
$rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($rdr.Read())
{
    Write ($rdr["MaterialNumber"], $rdr["Description"])
}
$rdr.Close()
$con.Close()


# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $errorMessage
})
```

The script is crafted in PowerShell, and I'm facing the following error message:

```bash
ERROR: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
```

This error indicates an issue with locating the ODBC driver specified in the connection string, making it challenging to connect to the database as intended.

Comment: You are missing the ODBC Data Source.  Go to Window Start button and type ODBC Data Sources.

Comment: @jdweng I run it on the azure function app, it is not a windows instance.

Comment: Not sure what platform you are using.  Is it SQL Server?  Do a google search for "azure app ODBC setup"  Looks like you are using System.Net which is a Microsoft library.

Comment: @jdweng I use PowerShell azure function app.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc?tabs=data-factory#create-a-linked-service-to-an-odbc-data-store-using-ui

Comment: Check this [link](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_ACCELERATOR_FOR_SAP_ASE/647582cc310341319e6e8d6f23f1f230/63ee40091a1847b886e3bcfe71ecb91a.html)

Comment: @Omid Erfanmanesh if your are running in azure, which platform you have created the azure function `Windows` or `Linux`. You are not importing any module to use ODBC driver in your code.

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya, I am using windows

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya in the connection string I used ```Driver={HDBODBC};```